# How can I justify that I can put the laplace operator under the integral?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, poisson-integrals

Consider the integral:

$ h(r, \theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} g(\phi) \frac{1-r^2}{1-2r \cos(\theta - \phi) + r^2} d\phi, r<1$

I want to show that $\Delta h=0$, but in order to do so, I need to justify this:

$\Delta \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} g(\phi) \frac{1-r^2}{1-2r \cos(\theta - \phi) + r^2} d\phi = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} g(\phi) \Delta \frac{1-r^2}{1-2r \cos(\theta - \phi) + r^2} d\phi$

That way, this becomes $0$, as the Poisson kernel is harmonic.

Comment: There's something not right about the integral, I think you have your letters mixed up

Comment: probably $d\phi$ so that its a convolution integral

Comment: Whoops,... yeah it's $d\phi$

Comment: It looks a bit like the Leibniz integral rule. It's just the $\phi$-component of $\Delta$ which seems a bit fishy to pull into the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved the problem.
Seems like I can somehow relate the function to a regular analytic complex function, as shown in the last few pages of this: [https://www.math.uh.edu/~shanyuji/Complex/Notes/N27.pdf](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Eshanyuji/Complex/Notes/N27.pdf)